# Is there break function in python (for PyCharm or other IDE)?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, breakpoints, break

There is `__debugbreak` function in C++.

I need to use similar function that breaks run-time with resume possibility in my Python code (with PyCharm IDE).

Comment: In PyCharm put the cursor in the line you want to break and CRTL+F8

Comment: @DeepSpace
No no. I want to use speical assertions to put conditional breakpoint

Comment: You can add a conditional breakpoint...

Comment: @DeepSpace, with step out of function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the pdb (and ipdb) module which provide interactive debuggers.

You can use

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

to insert a breakpoint wherever you want.

I'm not sure how these will work with PyCharm (for which you should just be able to click to add a breakpoint anyway) but the literal answer to your question is "yes".

Using `ipdb` from the command line is a very easy way to debug your Python code.

See https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pdb.html

Comment: I use Pycharm, and this is still my main manner for breakpoint debugging.

Comment: @Roman, but I can't do it. I only got the warning: PYDEV DEBUGGER WARNING:
sys.settrace() should not be used when the debugger is being used.
This may cause the debugger to stop working correctly.
If this is needed, please check: 
http://pydev.blogspot.com/2007/06/why-cant-pydev-debugger-work-with.html
to see how to restore the debug tracing back correctly.

Comment: @Broly Start a news script, paste `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in and run it normally.  You should get an interactive breakpoint that you can work in.  This works both if you just use Pycharm to create a Terminal, or if you `Ctrl+Shift+F10` (right click, run).  If this is what you want, then work it into your code.

Comment: @Roman It does not gave any effect. Only this message: 
--Return--
> c:\users\broly\applications\baseapp\appsettings.py(17)<module>()->None
-> import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb)

Comment: @Broly I do think it is working.  The `(Pdb)` at the beginning of the line means you are inside the debugger.  You can tell, because if you press `Ctrl-C` you'll get a `KeyboardInterrupt`.  A quick demo:  `for i in range(5): print(i)` prints 0-4.  `for i in range(5): print(i); import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` will print 0, and then put you into the debugger.  If you then call `i`, it will return 0, because you are still in the first round of the loop.  (Note, please don't ever string commands together in python with `;` as I've done above.  Put them in new lines)

Comment: @Roman, I know how to insert the `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in VIM using keyboard shortcuts repeatably. Is there a way to insert such statements in Pycharm repeatably?